# Issue : Installing Opencv and python 2.7.5 on Mac

Tags: c++, python, macos, opencv, numpy

I am trying to install OpenCV on MacOs
I am folwoing this tutorial 
http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2013/08/22/update-installing-opencv-on-mac-mountain-lion/

When I reach this point, I got this error

```
$ brew install opencv

opencv: Unsatisfied dependency: numpy
External Python cannot `import numpy`. Install with:
  pip-2.7 install numpy
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I installed NumPy by using  https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack 
I used as well :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
$ git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
$ cd numpy
$ python setup.py build && python setup.py install
$ brew install gfortran
$ cd ../scipy
$ python setup.py build && python setup.py install
```

when I go to install OpenCV I got this problem :

```
$ brew install opencv
opencv: Unsatisfied dependency: numpy
External Python cannot `import numpy`. Install with:
  pip-2.7 install numpy
```

but I still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause for your problem is that you have several python versions on your system (The default installation that comes with OSX and your SciPy superpack installation, and possibly others) and brew doesn't find the installation for which you have Numpy.

I would recommend installing OpenCV via [Macports](http://www.macports.org/), which will save you a lot of headaches related to choosing which version of python to use.

Comment: Yes, and the port is quite actively maintained - Usually there is only a very short wait between the release of a new major OpenCV version and when it is made available on macports. In any case, the dependencies will be installed by macports which allows you to compile different versions of the library yourself. Handy!